# PhpStorm not indexing WordPress hooks

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm

After following all the topics at [PhpStorm Help pages for WordPress](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/wordpress-aware-coding-assistance.html)  the hook navigation in PhpStorm is still not working.

Comment: It makes sense to share a code snippet that describes what doesn't work exactly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify WordPress Installation Path.

[image: Check the image.]